# How can I compare percentage of a colour at different points in an image?

Tags: image, image-processing

I have an image in which the intensity of Red increases from left to right (similar to a spectrum). Is it possible for me to compare the intensity of red at two different points?

I need to the values of the intensities of red at equal distances for a science project. Is there a script that I can use (in Gimp for example) or can anyone tell me how I can create my own using Python or Scilab? Other tools and languages are also welcome but these two are the ones I'm familiar with.

Thanks. Please comment if my question is not clear enough. I'll try to improve it based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You image is a matrix where each entry (pixel) is composed by the red, green and blue components. Usually each R, G, B value is in the range 0 to 255, but that can be vary depending on the image format.

To compare the red intensity at two diferent points, extract the the Red component of the pixel at these two positions. You will have two values that you can compare.

Answer (score 0):

If your spectrum is of *intensity* i.e. from maximum red (r=255) to black (r=0), then the pixel value of the R channel (of RGB) can be used for the relative calculation (ratio or difference).
If the spectrum is of *saturation* i.e. from red (full saturated) to grey (completely de-saturated) then you can use the saturation value as your measure.
If you give an example image it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make it easier for you: I don't certainly know about GIMP, but I've done this in VB .NET Just some code like the below. If you want to get the percentage, it's just math: as others users told you, you will get three values corresponding to Red, Green and Blue. This values are from 0 to 255, so 255 means 100% and 0 means 0%. Just get a function to obtain the percentage:

```
Function getPerc(color) 'color can be R, G, B

getPerc = (color * 100) / 255

End Function
```

There you are. The code to get the colors can be adapted from:

```
Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Application.DoEvents()

    ' Load the image
    Dim bm1 As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(txtFile1.Text)

    ' Make a difference image.
    Dim wid As Integer = bm1.Width
    Dim hgt As Integer = bm1.Height

    ' Create some variables
    Dim red As Byte, blue As Byte, green As Byte
    Dim color As color

    'Go pixel by pixel
    For x As Integer = 0 To wid - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To hgt - 1
            color = bm1.GetPixel(x, y)
            red = color.R
            blue = color.B
            green = color.G

            'your code here
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

(which is actually adapted by me from http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_image_compare.html )